# INSERT & Values (Image)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What i am need to find out is their a way to insert an image into every row using the INSERT and VALUES. So when the new product row is created during the query the image be inserted with the data.
For Example:

```
INSERT "Toy"("ToyID",Image,"ToyDescription")
VALUES (100, some image, 'Some Description')
GO
```

Each product will need an image associated with the data for my program this is not a website I am displaying the information including the image into a DataGrid.

The statement below is fine if you have a table that is uploading to store images.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(Document varbinary(max))
INSERT INTO myTable(Document)
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Image1.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB)
```

Comment: R u looking for this [`store and retrieve images from SQL server database`](http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource21-How-to-store-and-retrieve-images-from-SQL-server-database-using-aspnet.aspx.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Insert` from `Select` statement Syntax

```
INSERT Toy
       (ToyID,
        Image,
        ToyDescription)
SELECT 100,
       *,
       'Some Description'
FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Image1.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB)Rs
```